# Apple Touch Icon: Is it possible to update on the favicon on a web-mobile app for iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile

Is it possible to push update on the favicon (ex. apple-touch-icon.png) on a web-mobile app for iOS?
I mean, I saw a weather app that uses the actual app icon to update the temperature...

is it possible in your html5 web app (saved to your home screen)?

to be precise i just saw it working on this web app: pattern.dk/sun
and their icon displays exactly the realtime temperature, is that just a trick maybe??

UPDATE
The icon doesn't really update in real-time but only when you open and closes the app. still interesting though.

Comment: Are you asking to display a badge on a app icon on iOS' springboard?

Comment: the Apple Touch Icon, the icon you see when you bookmark a website ( "Save to Home Screen" ) from the mobile browser on iOs device

Comment: The important information would be, if u are asking for a badge, as «push» does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the trick

i'm adding a time stamp to the icon filename like:

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="favicon.png?<?php echo $date->format('U'); ?>" /> 
//this is a PHP piece of code but you generat a timestamp in any way you want
```

so anytime you open the boomark the icon app refresh itself

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7.1 the web app icon seems to update even if the filename is the same.